# Sourcesafe window stuck behind Visual Studio

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Among the seemingly neverending problems with microsoft visual sourcesafe, i have now done a full 'get' on a project, only for sourcesafe to draw a prompt window which, although i can see fine, i cannot click on or select.

More annoyingly it has totally locked visual studio so it seems both are 'unclickable' while waiting for each other to do something.

Any keyboard shortcuts or *any* suggestions?

Why is vss so terrible, some parts seem well written while other parts are totally awful.

Comment: Try Alt+TAB to cycle through the windows until it has focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move to Subversion.... Sorry, that's about the best advice I can give you.

Answer (score 3):

To be fair, I think this could happen with the Visual Studio source control integration for *any* VCS, however as previously mentioned - once you ditch SourceSafe, you'll never go back.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem, and it seems to occur if Visual Studio loses focus because you tab to another task while waiting. If you allow Visual Studio to keep focus until the entire Get Latest is done, you should be able to click the dialogs.

However, I do agree with Russell, and I am also advocating that all new work at our company be moved to SVN.

Comment: I asked this almost three years ago! Our company has long moved to SVN, which has turned out to be an excellent decision.

Answer (score 0):

Following this for me did the trick (always forget about it but just had it happen in legacy project; not for sourcesafe but something else): https://superuser.com/questions/634877/ssms-2008-is-stuck-because-connect-to-server-window-is-hiding

Alt + Space, then select Maximize brought the window right up.